# how to query across multiple partition keys in an azure storage table?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have the following use case:

- user requests creation of a widget.  A new record is created with the details in a "request" partition in my storage table.
- when the request is fulfilled - the original request is deleted from the "request" partition and created anew in the "provisioned" partition.

When it comes to querying for a widget - I need to search both the request and provisioned partitions.
From reading the docs, it seems that I can create filters?  But it seems to be a lot of overhead because I know i will only ever have 1 record returned (hopefully, unless I have a bug).
But it seems I have to add a lot of logic to handle pagination.

So far this is what i'm moving from:

```
 entity = tableClient.GetEntity<TableEntity>(
        "requested",
         requestId);
```

To something like this:

```
            //entity = tableClient.GetEntity<TableEntity>(
            //                    "requested",
            //                    requestId); 

            List<string> filters = new List<string>();
            filters.Add($"PartitionKey eq '{"requested"}'");
            filters.Add($"PartitionKey eq '{"provisioned"}'");
            filters.Add($"RowKey eq '{requestId}'");
            string filter = String.Join(" and ", filters);
            //should only ever return one ... but ...
            var entities =  tableClient.QueryAsync<TableEntity>(filter);

            await foreach (Page<TableEntity> page in entities.AsPages())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is a new page!");
                foreach (TableEntity qEntity in page.Values)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"i found this request:  {qEntity.GetString("requestId")} with status: {"status"}");
                }
            }
```

This code presently doesn't work - will need to debug it.  but I thought i'd check to see if there's an easier way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Point queries are the cheapest and simplest kind of query. Cross-partition queries are the mose expensive and most complex kind of query. If you can just do two (simultaneous) point queries, that would be what I recommend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend first writing a `TryGetEntityAsync` extension method:

```
public static async Task<Response<T>?> TryGetEntityAsync<T>(this TableClient tableClient, string partitionKey, string rowKey, IEnumerable<string>? select = default, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) where T : class, ITableEntity, new()
{
  try
  {
    return await tableClient.GetEntityAsync<T>(partitionKey, rowKey, select, cancellationToken);
  }
  catch (RequestFailedException ex) when (ex.Status == 404)
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then, you can do two point queries one at a time:

```
var entity =
    (await tableClient.TryGetEntityAsync<TableEntity>("requested", requestId)) ??
    (await tableClient.TryGetEntityAsync<TableEntity>("provisioned", requestId));
```

or concurrently:

```
var requestedEntityTask = tableClient.TryGetEntityAsync<TableEntity>("requested", requestId);
var provisionedEntityTask = tableClient.TryGetEntityAsync<TableEntity>("provisioned", requestId);
var entities = await Task.WhenAll(requestedEntityTask, provisionedEntityTask);
var entity = entities[0] ?? entities[1];
```

Comment: Sorry, can you just tell me where I would define the new method?  I tried pasting into the same class where the get logic is right now, but I'm getting an error:  'TableClient' does not contain a definition for 'TryGetEntityAsync' and no accessible extension method 'TryGetEntityAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'TableClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) csharp(CS1061)

Comment: @dot: Extension methods must be in a `static class`. You can name it whatever you want.

Comment: After putting it in a separate static class, the error I get on the line within the try{} block is cs0411.  "The type arguments for method 'TableClient.GetEntityAsync<T>(string, string, IEnumerable<string>, CancellationToken)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Comment: @Dot: Had a typo. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Considering an entity will be present in just one partition only, you could change your code to something like:

```
List<string> filters = new List<string>();
filters.Add($"(PartitionKey eq 'requested' and RowKey eq '{requestId}')");
filters.Add($"(PartitionKey eq 'provisioned' and RowKey eq '{requestId}')");
string filter = String.Join(" or ", filters);
//should only ever return one ... but ...
var entities =  tableClient.QueryAsync<TableEntity>(filter);

await foreach (Page<TableEntity> page in entities.AsPages())
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is a new page!");
    foreach (TableEntity qEntity in page.Values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"i found this request:  {qEntity.GetString("requestId")} with status: {"status"}");
    }
}
```

Comment: would it be more efficient if i actually created 2 separate tables?  One for just provisioned records and the other for requests?   I don't know yet what I would use for the respective partition keys... but just trying to think about what will be most response.  Client will query based on the request ID,,, and I won't know the status.

Comment: I don’t see any benefit of creating 2 separate tables. You could do 2 separate point queries if you like and that would be the same as creating 2 tables.